# How to use form partial for new and edit action with admin routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How should I setup url for that partial form to be able use it for `create` and `update` action.

Right now I have to set up two urls: `admin_faculty_path` for `update` and `admin_faculties_path` for `create` action.

```
# admin/faculties/_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for @faculty, html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :department_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: params[:department_id] } if params[:department_id]
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :name_en
  = f.submit
```

Routes:

```
admin_faculties    POST   /admin/faculties(.:format)              admin/faculties#create
new_admin_faculty  GET    /admin/faculties/new(.:format)          admin/faculties#new
edit_admin_faculty GET    /admin/faculties/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/faculties#edit
admin_faculty      GET    /admin/faculties/:id(.:format)          admin/faculties#show
                   PUT    /admin/faculties/:id(.:format)          admin/faculties#update
```

Controller:

```
# faculties_controller.rb
  def new
    @faculty = Faculty.new
  end

  def create
    @faculty = Faculty.new(params[:faculty])

    if @faculty.save
      redirect_to admin_departments_path,
        notice: t('activerecord.successful_save_data')
    else
      flash[:error] = t('activerecord.save_data_error_html')
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @faculty = Faculty.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @faculty = Faculty.find(params[:id])

    if @faculty.update_attributes(params[:faculty])
      redirect_to admin_departments_path,
        notice: t('activerecord.successful_save_data')
    else
      flash[:error] = t('activerecord.save_data_error_html')
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the namespace to the form:

```
simple_form_for [:admin, @faculty]
```

See for example

- [Rails Routes Namespaces and form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for)