# Invalid path in form using namespace routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some routes under a namespace

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :pages
end
```

what should i write in the page form in order to perform POST and PUT request?
I tried with

`= form_for(@page, url: page_path(@page)) do |f|`

but i get this error

```
undefined method `page_path'
```

but it works fine when i try to edit a page.
Here my routes for page

```
pages GET    /pages(.:format)                        pages#index
POST   /pages(.:format)                        pages#create
new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)                    pages#new
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)               pages#edit
page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)                    pages#show
PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)                    pages#update
DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)                    pages#destroy
```

thank you

Comment: Try with `admin_page_path(@page)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Routes Namespaces and form\_for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
= form_for [:admin, @page] do |f|
```

The namespace will be added to the page resource path.