# 'no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer' with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving

> no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer

with the following code:

```
<%= form_for  @question, admin_questions_path do |f| %>         
     <%= f.label :question %>   
     <%= f.text_area :question %>
<% end %>
```

But when I change the `form_for` method as follows; the form renders correctly.

```
<%= form_for  [:admin, @question] do |f| %>
```

What is the difference between the code? If the incorrect code is routing to the `create` method of the `Admin::QuestionsController` with the path `admin_questions_path` why does it not work? I am new to rails and namespacing, so I may be missing something completely obvious.

Edit:

The questions controller is namespaced under admin.

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :questions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

Comment: Is admin_questions a join table? Is Admin a model? Does QuestionsController inherit from Admin? I'm kind of new to Rails, too, and your setup seems unusual.

Comment: Is anything [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for) useful?

Comment: @Jason In fact that is useful, thanks. The answer stated, "In the view you should write url explicitly because you have variable in controller other than controller name." Meaning I should use `:url => admin_questions_path`, rather than just `admin_questions_path`.

Comment: Read this : http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/polymorphic-routes/

Answer (score 5):

The first example should be syntactic sugar for writing the following (if i'm not mistaken):

```
form_for [@question, admin_questions_path] do |f|
```

Where you most likely wanted:

```
form_for @question, url: admin_questions_path do |f|
```

Your second form uses polymorphic routing to automatically determine the correct route, this is useful if you want to use the same form for editing and creating. The link Arup provided should be helpful about that topic, as is the guide about routing at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: a million thnxs