# Rails form_for (new) redirect to show after submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm using the admin session to create a new client. When I submit the form I need it to redirect to that client show page but the @client id is equal to nil at that point. I'm using devise for the authentication, so when the admin creates the client it goes directly to the client homepage. I need to go to the "Admin" client index. Thanks for your help.

```
<%= form_for @client, :url => client_path(@client) do |f| %>

  <p> <%= f.label :name, "Empresa" %> <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p> <%= f.label :email %> <%= f.text_field :email %> </p>
  <p> <%= f.label :password %> <%= f.text_field :password %> </p>
  <p> <%= f.label :contact %> <%= f.text_field :contact %></p>

  <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Admin"* client index.

If it's [namespaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for), you'll need to deal with the namespace in all of your object & path references:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @client] do |f| %> #-> sends to admin/clients#create
```

This assumes you're using a namespaced `Admin::ClientsController` controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   resources :clients, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end

#app/controllers/admin/clients_controller.rb
class Admin::ClientsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
      @clients = Client.all
   end

   def new
      @client = Client.new
   end

   def create
      @client = Client.new client_params
      @client.save
   end

end
```

---

As an aside, you need to **ensure you're not using HTML as a styling mechanism**.

I see people using `<p>` and `<br />` for *styling* all the time; it's wrong. You have an entire CSS pipeline to style your forms:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
form input {
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/qgk4dy3j/

Comment: Thanks Rich, I just got it to work. Thanks also for the CSS recommendation ( I was just testing, so I added those tags to have a clear view) however I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a new client instance on clients_controller.rb method new ?
also on your form I believe that `<%= form_for @client do |f| %>` is sufficient
Example:

```
 def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params) 
    if @client.save
      redirect_to @client
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Thales, but it is not going to the client controller because I'm using devise for the authentication. So, when the admin creates the client it goes directly to the client homepage. I wanted to go to the "Admin" client index. I hope I am clear