# Routing Issue in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have created a form useing form_for -

```
 = form_for @category, url: url_for(:controller => 'admin/category',:action => new_record ? "create" : "update"), name: 'udfFieldForm', id: 'udfFieldForm',:method =>'POST', remote: true do |f|
```

controller is look like-

```
 class Admin::CategoryController < ApplicationController
   def create
   end
   def update
   end
 end
```

route defined as -

```
namespace :admin do
   get 'category/:action' => 'category#index', :as => :category
   resource :categories
end
```

When i have submit  form it through an error like -

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'category' could not be found for AdminController):

Here category is a controller under admin directory but it's looking for category action in admin controller. here i want to call category controler.

Please help me , where is the issue?

Comment: it's through error - No route matches [GET] "/category"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need To Update Routes Like as with in admin namesapce

```
post 'category/:action'=> 'category', action: :create
patch 'category/:action'=> 'category', action: :update
```

Answer (score 0):

The application expects a controller named `AdminController` with a method named `category`, but it cannot find it. That is what the error message says and this how you created the link `...url: url_for(:controller => 'admin/category'...`

I think that is wrong, since obviously you don't have a `category` method/action in your `AdminController`.

Comment: category is not an action its a controller under admin directory like admin/category ,and action in category controller are create and update

Comment: Well, but that is your error. You have to correct that now. The app is looking for `category` in `AdminController`, but you want it to be a *CategoryController* under admin namespace. Correct your form link accordingly.